# Disconnect From Facebook User On Quickblox Logout In iOS App

Tags: ios, quickblox

I have an iOS app where I'm trying to implement functionality so that a user who has logged in to QuickBlox via Facebook (via `QBUsers logInWithSocialProvider`)can logout and then log in as a different Facebook user.

I'm logging out using

```
[[QBChat instance] logout];
[QBUsers logOutWithDelegate:nil];
```

but when I login subsequently (again via `QBUsers logInWithSocialProvider`) the Facebook UI is not displayed - I'm logged in as the previous user.

How can I log out so that the user is disconnected from the facebook account they were previously logged in as and are able to login under a different account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to clear cookies to completely do facebook logout

Try something like this:

```
    // Clear cookies
    NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
    NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    for (cookie in [storage cookies]){
        NSString* domainName = [cookie domain];
        NSRange domainRange = [domainName rangeOfString:@"facebook"];
        if(domainRange.length > 0){
            [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
        }
    }
```